# Doubt in parallel axis theorem exercise

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

My teacher solved a parallel axis theorem in class and I don't understand one of the steps he did

The exercise consists of a coin of mass $m$ and radius $r$ moving on circles inside of a cone, the scheme figure is as it follows.

[image]

In the first part of the excercise we have to compute the moment of inertia of the coin at the point B, where G is the center of mass. He used the Parallel axis theorem: $$\textbf{I}_B=\textbf{I}_G+m\cdot d^2$$

We knew that $$\textbf{I}_G= \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}mr^2 $$

The problem is he then did

$$\textbf{I}_B=\textbf{I}_G+ m\begin{pmatrix}
BG^2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & BG^2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{4}r^2+BG^2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{4}r^2+BG^2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}r^2
\end{pmatrix}m$$
and I don't know how he did that. I appreciate any insights, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\textbf{I}_B=\textbf{I}_G+ m\begin{pmatrix}
BG^2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & BG^2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

you obtain this result from here :

$$\mathbf I_B=\mathbf I_G-m\,\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-{\it BG}&0\\  {\it BG}
&0&0\\  0&0&0\end {array} \right] 
\,\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-{\it BG}&0\\  {\it BG}
&0&0\\  0&0&0\end {array} \right] 
$$

where the parallel axis is
$$\vec r=[0~,0~,BG]^T$$

Comment: Yes, The 3D parallel axis therem is $${\bf I}_B = {\bf I}_G -m [ \vec{BG}\times] [\vec{BG}\times]$$ where $$[\vec{BG}\times] = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -z & y \\ z & 0 & -x \\ -y & x & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ There are other forms like $${\bf I}_B = {\bf I}_G + m [ \vec{BG}\times] [\vec{BG}\times]^\intercal$$ or $${\bf I}_B = {\bf I}_G +m \left( (\vec{BG} \cdot \vec{BG}) {\bf 1} - \vec{BG} \otimes \vec{BG} \right)$$

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't realise he had used the vector which points the disk as the parallel axis.